# Excel VBA - Set variable to text and cell value

Tags: vba, excel

Still working on my first VBA script, but I'm stuck. I want to set a variable to a cell value AND text but it only lets me set a variable to one or the other, not both.

Example:

```
Dim Week As Range
Dim WeekCurrent As String

Set Week = .Range("F4")

If Week.Value = "Initial Week" Then
    WeekCurrent = "Initial Week"
Else
    WeekCurrent = "Week #" Week.Value
End If
```

Desired Result: "Initial Week" or "Week #x" to call on later.

I can either set it to the `"Week #"` text or to `Week.Value` but not both. I'm sure I'm using the wrong declaration or something.

As of right now, my workaround involves changing any instances I want to use this variable into an IF THEN ELSE and doubles the amount of coding because I have to duplicate the code. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `WeekCurrent = "Week #" Week.Value` ??? Also, try to avoid declaring a variable with the name of `Week` which is an Excel saved word

Comment: As I mentioned. I want to call on that string where week.value is a number and it outputs "Week #n" where n = week.value.

Comment: so you meant to use `WeekCurrent = "Week #"  & Week.Value`

Comment: I knew it was something stupid I was missing. This was the fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this may be:

```
If IsNumeric(Week) Then WeekCurrent = "Week #" & Week Else WeekCurrent = Week
```

Comment: Nice! Like this, more efficient and flexible

Comment: I'm sure you may be aware you can refer to excel cells using  Cells(row#,column#).

Comment: Then by using variables for the row and/or column numbers you can be a bit more dynamic on which cell you reference or easily construct code to loop through and process a range of cells.